# Can't install Phidgets ROS driver

Tags: ros

I have installed the Phidgets libraries following the following link and the "Hello World" example was working, but when I install the [Phidgets ROS driver](https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/phidgets_drivers), I get this error:

> fatal error: libphidgets/phidget21.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.

What's causing this? The libraries have been installed by the Linux driver, right?

Answer (score 1):

Phidgets, in their infinite wisdom desired to abandon the "phidget21" architecture and now have a completely different and incompatible phidgets22 driver architecture.  When you installed the libraries from their web site, you can only get the version 22 driver architecture :(  -- hint, version 21 is still out there on GitHub, so if you go find it, download and install everything should work as expected.  Someone will need to migrate all the ROS code to the newer version 22 architecture for this to work as expected.